# How to one proxy server

Tags: c#, .net, webproxy

I want to create one proxy server in c# which will accept request from client and route the request with another real proxy and return result back to client.

For Example:

1. Client send a request for www.google.com with proxy as my server IP.
2. So, First this request will come to my proxy server.
3. Then my proxy server need to route this request to google server with another proxy. So, the google would never the IP of client and my proxy server, it would be only knowing proxy address which is added by my proxy server.
4. Result need to beck to client who originated the request.

Comment: You will need a lot Proxy IP's since Google will BAN your requests after some number of requests. Only way is to create / delete proxy servers on Go. Maybe check this out. https://createproxy.com/api/#obj-c_get_proxy